# What use is apache's `Require all denied` directive?

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server

The docs state that this works similar to the old `Deny from all`.

While I see how `Require all granted` works fine, without a new `Order` directive `Require all denied` is basically a placebo:

```
Require all denied
Require local
Require all denied
```

This will still grant access if the `Require local` condition is met.

The only place `Require all denied` would have any effect is if you specifically created a `<RequireAll>` section and put it in it

```
<RequireAll>
  Require all denied
  Require local
</RequireAll>
```

But in that case you could replace the entire section with:

```
Require all denied
```

Or

```
Require not all granted
```

Or even

```
# Nothing at all, defaults to denied
```

Unless you use `AuthMerging And`, doesn't this make it useless?